# cannot make VSCode Snippet $TM_CURRENT_LINE work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I created this custom snippet to get line number with alert

```
  "alert-line": {
    
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    
    "prefix": "al",

    "body": [
 
        "alert(`Line $TM_CURRENT_LINE`);",

    ],
    
    "description": "alert line"
  
  },
```

as output I get something weird

```
alert(`Line             al`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `TM_LINE_NUMBER` or `TM_LINE_INDEX`, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables.

Your output is correct for `$TM_CURRENT_LINE` which is the text on the current line.  And since your prefix was `al` and you typed that on an line with a few tabs only - that was the current line's text.